# Objective-C to Swift Conversion Issue

Tags: objective-c, swift, function, variables

I am trying to convert Apple's own sample code which is only written in Objective-C in to Swift.

This is what's in Objective C

.h

```
@import UIKit;

@class AVCaptureSession;

@interface AAPLPreviewView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) AVCaptureSession *session;

@end
```

.m

```
@import AVFoundation;

#import "AAPLPreviewView.h"

@implementation AAPLPreviewView

+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer class];
}

- (AVCaptureSession *)session
{
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = (AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)self.layer;
    return previewLayer.session;
}

- (void)setSession:(AVCaptureSession *)session
{
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = (AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)self.layer;
    previewLayer.session = session;
}

@end
```

So far, this what I came up for Swift:

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class CamPreviewLayer: UIView
{
    var session: AVCaptureSession!
    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass
    {
        return AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    }

    func session() -> AVCaptureSession {
        var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = self.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
        return previewLayer.session
    }

    func setSession(session: AVCaptureSession) {
        let previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = self.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
        previewLayer.session = session
    }
}
```

My Swift code has 3 errors.

Comment: u don't need `var session: AVCaptureSession!`. can u show which error do u have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `var session: AVCaptureSession` like this.

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class AVPreviewView : UIView {
    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
        return AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
    }
    func session () -> AVCaptureSession {
        return (self.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).session
    }

    func setSession(session : AVCaptureSession) -> Void {
        (self.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).session = session;
        (self.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;

    }
}
```

Hope it help!

Comment: copy paste from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480383/avcapturevideopreviewlayer-and-preview-from-camera-position :)